# "numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_support" error message after running SelectKBest in Scikit Learn

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I met a question related to this old one: [The easiest way for getting feature names after running SelectKBest in Scikit Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839112/the-easiest-way-for-getting-feature-names-after-running-selectkbest-in-scikit-le/50457806?noredirect=1#comment87929213_50457806)

When trying to use "get_support()" to get the selected features, I got the error message:

> numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_support

I would greatly appreciate your kind help!

Jeff

Answer (score 6):

Without doing fitting you cannot get support. You need to do the fitting so that the selector can analyze the data, and then call `get_support()` on the selector, not the output of `fit_transform()`

Currently you are doing something like:

```
selector = SelectKBest()

#fit_transform returns the data after selecting the best features
new_data = selector.fit_transform(old_data, labels)

#so you are trying to access get_support() on new data, which is not possible
new_data.get_support()
```

After you call `fit()` or `fit_transform()`, do this:

```
# get_support is a method of SelectKBest class
selector.get_support()
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. What you said was exactly what happened. My own answer is definitely not as clear as what you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think I found out the reason why I got the errors. I used "get_support()" on the results after fit() or fit_transform(), which led to the error message.

I should have used the "get_support()" on the selector itself (but still need to use selector to do fit() or fit_transform() first).

Thanks!

Jeff