# Sentiment analysis Pipeline, problem getting the correct feature names when feature selection is used

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, tf-idf, feature-selection

In the following example I use a twitter dataset to perform sentiment analysis. I use sklearn pipeline to perform a sequence of transformations, add features and add a classifer. The final step is to visualise the words that have the higher predictive power. It works fine when I don't use feature selection. However, when I do use it the results that I get make no sense. I suspect that when feature selection is applied the order of the text features changes. Is there a way to work around that?

**The code below has been updated to include the correct answer**

```py
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

features= [c for c in df.columns.values if c  not in ['target']]
target = 'target'

#train test split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[features], df[target], test_size=0.2,stratify = df5[target], random_state=0)

#Create classes which allow to select specific columns from the dataframe

class NumberSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[[self.key]]

class TextSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]

class ColumnExtractor(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, cols):
        self.cols = cols

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # stateless transformer
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # assumes X is a DataFrame
        Xcols = X[self.cols]

        return Xcols

class DummyTransformer(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self.dv = None

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        # assumes all columns of X are strings
        Xdict = X.to_dict('records')
        self.dv = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
        self.dv.fit(Xdict)
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        # assumes X is a DataFrame
        Xdict = X.to_dict('records')
        Xt = self.dv.transform(Xdict)
        cols = self.dv.get_feature_names()
        Xdum = pd.DataFrame(Xt, index=X.index, columns=cols)

        # drop column indicating NaNs

        nan_cols = [c for c in cols if '=' not in c]
        Xdum = Xdum.drop(nan_cols, axis=1)
        Xdum.drop(list(Xdum.filter(regex = 'unknown')), axis = 1, inplace = True)

        return Xdum

def pipelinize(function, active=True):
    def list_comprehend_a_function(list_or_series, active=True):
        if active:
            return [function(i) for i in list_or_series]
        else: # if it's not active, just pass it right back
            return list_or_series
    return FunctionTransformer(list_comprehend_a_function, validate=False, kw_args={'active':active})

#function to plot the coeficients of the words in the text with the highest predictive power
def plot_coefficients(classifier, feature_names, top_features=50):

    if classifier.__class__.__name__ == 'SVC':
        coef = classifier.coef_
        coef2 = coef.toarray().ravel()
        coef1 = coef2[:len(feature_names)]

    else:
        coef1 = classifier.coef_.ravel()

    top_positive_coefficients = np.argsort(coef1)[-top_features:]
    top_negative_coefficients = np.argsort(coef1)[:top_features]
    top_coefficients = np.hstack([top_negative_coefficients, top_positive_coefficients])
     # create plot
    plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
    colors = ['red' if c < 0 else 'blue' for c in coef1[top_coefficients]]
    plt.bar(np.arange(2 * top_features), coef1[top_coefficients], color=colors)
    feature_names = np.array(feature_names)
    plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 1 + 2 * top_features), feature_names[top_coefficients], rotation=90, ha='right')
    plt.show()

#create a custome stopwords list
stop_list = stopwords(remove_stop_word ,add_stop_word )

#vectorizer
tfidf=TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf=True, stop_words = set(stop_list),ngram_range = (1,2))

#categorical features
CAT_FEATS = ['location','account']

#dimensionality reduction
pca = TruncatedSVD(n_components=200)

#scaler for numerical features
scaler = StandardScaler()

#classifier
model = SVC(kernel = 'linear', probability=True, C=1, class_weight = 'balanced')

text = Pipeline([('selector', TextSelector(key='content')),('text_preprocess', pipelinize(text_preprocessing)),('vectorizer',tfidf),('important_features',select)])
followers =  Pipeline([('selector', NumberSelector(key='followers')),('scaler', scaler)])
location = Pipeline([('selector',ColumnExtractor(CAT_FEATS)),('scaler',DummyTransformer())])
feats = FeatureUnion([('text', text), ('length', followers), ('location',location)])
pipeline = Pipeline([('features',feats),('classifier', model)])
pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

preds = pipeline.predict(X_test)

feature_names = text.named_steps['vectorizer'].get_feature_names()
feature_names = np.array(feature_names)[text.named_steps['important_features'].get_support(True)]

classifier = pipe.named_steps['classifier']

plot_coefficients(classifier, feature_names)
```

Before feature selection
[image]

After feature selection
[image]

To use feature selection I change the following lines of code from

```py
text = Pipeline([('selector', TextSelector(key='content')),
                 ('text_preprocess', pipelinize(text_preprocessing)),
                 ('vectorizer',tfidf)])
```

to

```py
select = SelectKBest(f_classif, k=8000)
text = Pipeline([('selector', TextSelector(key='content')),
                 ('text_preprocess', pipelinize(text_preprocessing)), 
                 ('vectorizer',tfidf), 
                 ('important_features',select)])
```

Comment: I want to point out that your use of the term "dimensionality reduction" is, arguably, incorrect. Usually dimensionality reduction refers to things such as PCA and SVD, that reduce a space by transforming. What you are doing is usually referred to as "feature selection". 

The feature selector indeed is the source of your problems, as it re-assigns the indices to new features. Here is a way to find the mapping: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39839112/the-easiest-way-for-getting-feature-names-after-running-selectkbest-in-scikit-le

Comment: @amdex I have updated my question. Unfortunately the approach that you suggested does not work in my case, probably because the vectorizer returns a sparce matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why this is happening

This is happening because Feature selection selects the most important features and discards the other, so that the indices don't make sense anymore.

Suppose you have the following example:

```
X = np.array(["This is the first document","This is the second document",
"This is the first again"])
y = np.array([0,1,0])
```

Obviously, the two main words that drive the classification are "first" and "second". With a pipeline similar to yours, you would do:

```
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()
sel = SelectKBest(k = 2)
pipe = Pipeline([('vectorizer',tfidf), ('select',sel)])
pipe.fit(X,y)

feature_names = np.array(pipe['vectorizer'].get_feature_names())
feature_names[pipe['select'].get_support(True)]

>>> array(['first', 'second'], dtype='<U8')
```

As a result, what you need to do is not only to get the features from the tfidf vectorization, but also to select the indices kept by the feature selection through `pipe['select'].get_support(True)`.

### What to change in your code

Hence, what you should change in your code is just adding this line of code:

```
feature_names = text.named_steps['vectorizer'].get_feature_names()
## Add this line
feature_names = feature_names[text['important_features'].get_support(True)]
##
classifier = pipe.named_steps['classifier']
plot_coefficients(classifier, feature_names)
```

Comment: your original answer produced an error but at the same time it gave me a good direction on how to solve the problem. I have updated your answer. Happy to accept your answer if you are happy with the edit.

Comment: Can you tell me if you get the error if you do this:    feature_names = np.array(feature_names)[text['important_features'].get_support(True)]   ?

Comment: When I use that I get a 'TypeError: 'Pipeline' object is not subscriptable' error. I think the problem is with the text['important_features'], it should be text.named_steps['important_features'].

Comment: It works when I use: feature_names = np.array(feature_names)[text.named_steps['select_best_features'].get_support(True)]. I have updated your answer.

Comment: I think this might be because of previous scikit learn versions, both should be equivalent indeed